# No Desktop Icons Using Compiz Wallpaper

Tags: icons, compiz, desktop-background, desktop-icons

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the Gnome Classic desktop.  Under CompizConfig I'm running the Desktop Cube and Wallpaper settings to have a cube with 4 different wallpapers.  When using CompizConfig Wallpaper, there are no desktop icons.  I can turn them back on via Ubuntu Tweak, but that reverts my wallpaper back to the default on all 4 viewports.  Is there a way to have the desktop icons show up while using CompizConfig Wallpaper, or do I just have to choose between having one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Open tweak tool and click, "Desktop" and on the first line there should be the option, "Have file manager manage the desktop" and make sure that it is set to, "on" instead of, "off". If this doesn't work maybe you may have to manually set the icon for the programs on the desktop. This you can achieve by going to your desktop in file manager and right clicking and selecting properties. Then just click on the icon of the desktop icon and go from there to select a new icon.

Comment: That's under Advanced System Settings, and I've tried that too.  Same effect as using Tweak tool to activate the icons.  I've tried going to Desktop in my file manager, but there's nothing in it.  Clicking on properties only lets me change the icon that represents the Desktop folder in the file manager.  I don't see any way of getting the icons to show back up on my actual desktop.